# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or URL. Received type object sails.js?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

CODE:(I would like to read the xlsx file and convert into Json. Here is my Code.When i uncomment those commented lines. Iam not getting any error and response too. If i comment those lines got above error. Can you help me?)

```
  exports.importSheet  = function(req, res, cb) {
       // console.log(req.file("files"))
      const XLSX = require('xlsx');
      const file_name = req.body.file_name
      console.log(file_name)
    // const fileType = req.file("files")
    // req.file("files").read(XLSX, function(err, files) {
    //   console.log(err)
    //   if (err) cb(res.serverError(err));
    //   else{
    //       console.log(files)
          const workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.file("files"));
          const sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames;
          let sheetIndex = 1;
          const df = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[sheetIndex-1]]);
          console.log(df);
          cb(null, df)
    //   }
    // })
   }
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with `.xlsx` file that you are trying to convert to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
 var XLSX = require('xlsx');

 exports.importSheet  = function(req, res, cb) {
       console.log(req.file("files"))
      const file_name = req.body.file_name
      req.file("files").upload(function(err, files) {
      if (err) cb(res.serverError(err));
       else{
          const workbook = XLSX.readFile(files[0].fd);
          const sheetNames = workbook.SheetNames;
          let sheetIndex = 1;
          const df = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetNames[sheetIndex-1]]);
          console.log(df);
          cb(null, df)
       }
     })
   }
```